# Swiping between screens using Scene2d

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, scene2d

I am quite familiar with scene2d now, but there is one thing I need to know before I create my full menu, how do I swipe between windows?

Say I have a main window where I start games etc., then I swipe to the right and get a window with options, or I swipe left and get my friends-list.

I am wondering, is this done using one `Screen` and several tables, or is it usually done using several `Screens`? That is, each window is it's own `Screen`and when I swipe I switch `Screens`? Or is it done all in one Screen, placing tables outside the viewport that u can then swipe to without changing `Screen`?

Hope I'm being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to swipe, to switch to options/friendlist, i guess you should use 1 `Screen` with multiple `Table`s on it. That is because if the user has to swipe to switch to options/friendlist, he expects a smooth "movement" to the left/right, not an instant switch.
If you instead use buttons (Options-button), you could sepparate them into different `Screen`s and when the button is pressed, you swithc to the new `Screen`.
So i guess it depends on the case and your personal taste.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was expecting just wanted to make sure :)